# Convolution with astropy

Tags: python, convolution, astropy

I am having a problem understanding how the convolution of two models is done in astropy. I want to convolve my function, centered around a certain value x, with a Gaussian with mean 0 and sigma > 0. However, when I try to plot the result of the convolution, the function is centered around ~x/2. I think I am missing something fundamental here but I couldn’t find anything apart from the basic example on astropy docs.

Here it is my code snippet:

```py
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from astropy.modeling.models import custom_model
from astropy.modeling import models
from astropy.convolution import convolve_models

from scipy.constants import alpha


@custom_model
def spectrum(x):
   me = 0.511
   eMax = 104.97

   E = np.sqrt(x*x + me*me)
   result = (1./eMax)*(alpha/(2*math.pi))*(np.log(4*E*E/me/me)-2.)*((E*E+eMax*eMax)/eMax/(eMax-E))

   result[result < 0] = 0
   return result

x = np.linspace(0,120,1000)
s = spectrum()
g1 = models.Gaussian1D(1, 0, 2)
conv = convolve_models(g1, s)

plt.plot(x, conv(x), 'k-')
plt.plot(x, s(x))
```

I expect the convoluted function to be centered around the original one, I don't think I understand what's going on.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what's going on either, but I did note that if I extended the range to be symmetric about the y-axis with `x = np.linspace(-120, 120, 1000)` I get something that's probably closer to what you're expecting: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqYP1.png  In the docs for [`convolve_fft`](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.convolution.convolve_fft.html#astropy.convolution.convolve_fft) it does say that the kernel is assumed to be centered, but when taking the range `(0, 120)` your kernel is off-center, whereas with the reflection it is centered.